# ¿Cómo reemplazar missing values en un dataframe de Python usando for in column y filtro booleano?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame de Pandas llamado `df_test` de 173 fil x 21 col. En el `index = 6` y columnas con las etiquetas `col16`, `col17` y `col18` están 3 str *"UN"* que debo cambiar por `numpy.nan` usando estas líneas (completando los espacios):

```
for column in ___:
    df_test.loc[____ == '____', column] = ____
```

También tengo una lista que contiene los nombres de las columnas donde están las tres cadenas a reemplazar:

```
columnas = ["col16", "col17", "col18"]
```

He probado muchas formas sin éxito, por ejemplo:

1. ```
   for column in df_test: 
       df_test.loc[df_test[columnas] == "UN", column] = np.nan
   ```

   > **Error:** ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 173.
2. ```
   for column in df_test: 
       df_test.loc[df_test["col16"] == "UN", column] = np.nan
   ```

   > **Error:** Cambia el valor requerido pero también todos los otros en las columnas a su izquierda.

Este es un *print screen* del `df_test` indicando el dtype (únicamente se observan las str "UN"):

[image: df_test]

¿Cómo selecciono únicamente las cadenas que debo cambiar usando el `for column in` y el filtro boleano?
¿El reemplazo lo puedo hacer para las 3 columnas al mismo tiempo o debe ser de una columna a la vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has estado bastante cerca en realidad con tu segundo intento:

```
df_test.loc[df_test["col16"] == "UN", column]
```

El problema es que esto selecciona cualquier fila que tenga como valor "UN" en la columna "col16" y cambia el valor de la columna sobre la que se esté iterando (y con `for column in df_test` iteras sobre todas).

La causa de que solo modifique las  situadas a la izquierda se debe a que cuando se llega a `df_test.loc[df_test["col16"] == "UN", "col16"]`, el valor de la columna "col16" se modifica, por lo que para la siguiente iteración ("col18") y sucesivas `df_test["col16"] == "UN"` ya no se cumple.

Puedes hacer:

```
columnas = ["col16", "col17", "col18"]
for column in columnas:
    df_test.loc[df_test[column] == "UN", column] = np.nan
```

o directamente:

```
for column in ("col16", "col17", "col18"):
    df_test.loc[df_test[column] == "UN", column] = np.nan
```

Si se tiene que sustituir todos los valores "UN" independientemente de la columna en la que estén debes iteras sobre todas las columnas mediante `for column in df_test`:

```
for column in df_test:
    df_test.loc[df_test[column] == "UN", column] = np.nan
```

El primer parámetro, `df_test[column] == "UN"` va a hacer que `loc` seleccione cualquier fila del DataFrame que cumpla la condición de tener el valor "UN" en la columna sobre la que se esté iterando en ese momento. El segundo argumento, `column` selecciona la columna en concreto dentro de esa fila concreta permitiendo asignar el nuevo valor.

> Hay que tener en cuanta que hay formas más directas y eficientes de hacer esto en este caso, por ejemplo:
>
> `df_test.replace("UN", np.nan, inplace=True)`